# Can we use symbolic link and hard link for directories?

Tags: directory, symlink, hard-link

I know we can do that for files. What about directories?

It seems that cpanel uses that a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most filesystem do not support hard links on directories. However, you can symlink directories.

You can bind mount a directory in Linux, which functions similar to a hard link from a user's perspective. Here is an example:

```
mount --bind /usr /home/user/foo
```

This is commonly used for chroot environments, since a symlink is relative the chroot's `/`, a bind mount can provide access to locations outside of the chroot.

Comment: Make that "no sane filesystem handles directory hardlinks"